# python itertools round robin with no duplications

Tags: python, python-itertools

I managed to modify the recipe for roundrobin in https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/itertools.html
to include a limit (stop when reaching X elements) - code below...

Now - what I really want is "stop when reaching X elements but with no element duplication".
Is it even possible? (because it is a generator...)

```
def roundrobin(limit, *iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
                limit -= 1
                if limit == 0:
                    return

        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

calling it with:

```
candidates = [['111', '222', '333'],['444','222','555']] 
list(roundrobin(4, *candidates))
```

I would like to get:

```
['111,'444','222','333']
```

and not:

```
['111,'444','222','222']
```

like I'm getting with the current code

Comment: Yes, of course it is possible. Add a `set` to keep track of elements yielded so far.

Comment: but limit is internal. Let's say I have a repetition, I want the roundrobin to "know" to yield another one...

Comment: That's fine - only decrement `limit` when you `yield`. Note that you can use `while pending and limit` rather than explicitly checking `limit == 0`.

Comment: So you are saying if I use set and not list it will not perform a yield?

Comment: I'm confused by your example. What's your expected output of `roundrobin('AAA', 'AA', 'A')`? Is each 'A' considered unique, or do you consider them duplicated?

Comment: @AndréLaszlo - since I'm actually transferring lists to roundrobin than in your example they will be considered duplicates

Comment: Ok, then I misunderstood. Can you give an example with lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible implementation - I've added a `set`, named `seen`, inside the generator function to keep track of the elements we've already `yield`ed. Note that this means that *all* elements in *every* `iterable` **must be hashable** (if they get reached), which is not a limitation of the base `roundrobin`.

```
def roundrobin_limited_nodupe(limit, *iterables):
    """A round-robin iterator duplicates removed and a limit.

        >>> list(roundrobin_limited_nodupe(6, 'ABC', 'DB', 'EFG'))
        ['A', 'D', 'E', 'B', 'F', 'C']  # only six elements, only one 'B'

    Notes:
      - Recipe credited to George Sakkis

    """
    pending = len(iterables)
    seen = set()  # keep track of what we've seen
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                candidate = next()
                if candidate not in seen:  # only yield when it's new
                    seen.add(candidate)
                    yield candidate
                    limit -= 1
                    if limit == 0:
                        return
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
```

Comment: a set inside... Well I thought there is something more sophisticated to do :)
Thanks

Comment: @Boaz the downside is that the `set` will keep on getting larger, which may be a memory problem with lots of large `iterables`, but it should be pretty efficient otherwise.

Comment: just a quick fix (if someone will get here for reference) - yield candidate should be before the limit -= 1, otherwise we don't get the last one