# Sorting a list of tuples such that grouping by key is not desired

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I have a list of IDs that represent users, and I'm writing a function to turn that list of IDs into a schedule of user matchups (pairings) like so:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The schedule related to this would look like:

```
week 1: (1, 2), (3, 4)
week 2: (1, 3), (2, 4)
week 3: (1, 4), (2, 3)
week 4: (1, 2), (3, 4) [repeat of week 1]
```

and so on. I was trying to do this with nested `for` loops based on the number of user IDs and the combinations resulting from that.

```
ids = [1,2,3,4]
matchups = []

#generate all the combinations of matchups
for subset in itertools.combinations(ids,2):
    matchups.append(subset)
```

This returns all the potential pairings as a list of tuples- great! That's the core of what I'm looking for. My issue now has been figuring out how to transform this into something useable. For example, the above code returns this list for `matchups`:

```
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
```

I was trying a complicated recursive function to build a list of the unique pairings for each week, then I realized that if I have the above list in the right order, I can simply use it to assign pairings from start to finish, regardless of week, and repeating when I reach the end. That is, I can just assign pairings to weeks using the known number of pairings needed per week and the known number of weeks.

To that end, I've been trying to figure out how to sort a list of tuples based on elements that are *not* equal. The `sorted()` method has many useful implementations this type of situation, but I can only get results where like results are grouped, such as the above.

I'd like to find a use of `sorted()` that will return the following, almost like an anti-sort:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 3), (2, 4), (1, 4), (2, 3)]
```

Is there a way to use `lambda` for this?

EDIT: I just realized that the 1st element needs to be paired with the 6th, 2nd with 5th, and 3rd with 4th. I don't know if this extends to the general case, but I expect its possible, because I've taken other steps to ensure there are always an even number of IDs.

Now I'm sure there's some way to interpolate the list to achieve this.

EDIT2: Looks like the previous hunch wasn't correct- it doesn't work with 6 IDs, and likely anything beyond that would fail too. I'm back to trying to figure out if there's a way to disperse instead of sort based on a key

Comment: `random.shuffle` is an anti-sort :)

Comment: Very true- I realized my terminology there wasn't great- it's more like I need to ensure uniqueness rather than grouping by key.

Comment: Why can't you use a for loop? The order of the second list is just `0 5 1 4 2 3`.

Comment: @pp_ How does that generalize beyond 4 elements though

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean when you say that you have to pair 1st-6th, 2nd-5th, and 3rd-4th.  What properties do you need with these pairs of pairs?  For instance, the 1st-6th pairing uses 2 twice and 4 not at all.

Comment: I'm talking about the output of `itertools.combinations()` with the provided `ids`: `[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]`. In that list, the `0` element and `5` elements can be matched.

Comment: You might also want to look into the `itertools` roundrobin implementation [in the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31559525/python-itertools-round-robin-with-no-duplications) could be helpful, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an implementation of the wikipedia round-robin tournament algorithm.

```
x = range(1, 11) #10 players

def round_robin(someIds):
    someIds = someIds[::2] + someIds[1::2]
    first, someIds = [someIds[0]], someIds[1:]
    n = len(someIds)
    for i in range(n):
        top = someIds[:n/2]
        bottom = someIds[n/2:]
        yield zip(first+top, bottom)
        someIds = someIds[-1:] + someIds[:-1]


for thing in round_robin(x):
    print thing
```

## Output

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)]
[(1, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9), (10, 2)]
[(1, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10), (2, 3)]
[(1, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9), (10, 2), (3, 4)]
[(1, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10), (2, 3), (4, 5)]
[(1, 7), (8, 9), (10, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
[(1, 8), (9, 10), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7)]
[(1, 9), (10, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)]
[(1, 10), (2, 3), (4, 5), (6, 7), (8, 9)]
```

Comment: This works, thank you. You and @Prune were right- I should have just looked into this from the get go

Comment: changed it so that it prints in the order that you were looking for

Comment: Thanks again- so I was using pythonfiddle.com to work on this, but when I try to run it in my home environment (Python 3.4) I get the following error: `TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__method`. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: I think python3 uses `//` for integer division instead of just a single `/` which indicates floating point op

Comment: Thanks a ton- I figured the fiddle site must have been on 2.x but didn't know python3 had a different operator for integer division.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you're looking for is the canonical [round-robin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament) scheduling algorithm.

List all your players in any order you find convenient, in two rows:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

Your first-round pairings are 1-5, 2-6, 3-7, 4-8.
For successive weeks, rotate all but the #1 position: the upper row shifts left, the bottom row shifts right; those that fall off the end (2 and 8) move up/down to the empty spot:

```
1 3 4 8
2 5 6 7
```

If you also need to balance home-away pairings, then after you're done with this cycling, go back and exchange the rows in every other week.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but is there an advantage to round-robin over the combinations in my post? Are they even different? I only have 4 IDs but I think the end result may be the same. Regardless, I'm happy with the output of tuples from the `combination()` method, I guess this is more of a sorting/list manipulation question.

Comment: The round-robin pairings generalize easily to any number of IDs and guarantees that each ID has a pairing in every group of N/2 pairings.  From your description, I thought that this was the point of your *anti-sort*.

Comment: I suppose it is, but at the same time I believe the output of the `combination()` method gives me what round-robin does too. Is there any package implementing round-robin?

Answer (score 1):

Potentially unidiomatic solution, but it works. Maybe someone can make it more pythonic? :D

```
def antisort(x):
    if len(x) > 0:
        return [x[0]] + antisort(x[-1:0:-1])
    else:
        return []

>>> antisort([(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)])
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 3), (2, 4), (1, 4), (2, 3)]
```

This slice notation just takes everything after the first element and reverses it:

```
x[-1:0:-1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer- it looks like the hunch I had in my edit wasn't correct, because this works for 4 elements but not 6

Answer (score 1):

This is what I meant in my comment:

```
a = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (2, 3), (2, 4), (3, 4)]
new = []

i, j = len(a)-1, 0

for n in range(i+1):
    if n % 2:
        new.append(a[i])
        i -= 1
    else:
        new.append(a[j])
        j += 1

print(new)
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2), (3, 4), (1, 3), (2, 4), (1, 4), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: This works with 4 elements but not with more- it appears the hunch in my edit wasn't right. But thank you

Comment: @dkhaupt Why 4? The list has 6 elements. Or do you mean the weeks?

Comment: Yes- the tuple output has 6 elements, sorry- I meant the ID list that generates the tuple output. With 4 IDs, this works, but when I increase to 6 IDs, it no longer works